# Linq cast object

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to check if one exists before adding but casting within `.Any` does not work.

People is `ObservableCollection` of objects because each can be different class (each has `FirstLastName` property).

```
ObservableCollection<object> People = new ObservableCollection<object>();

foreach (cEmployee t in Group1)
{
  if (!People.Any((cEmployee)x => x.FirstLastName == t.FirstLastName) 
      People.Add(new cEmployee(t));              
}
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: x.FirstLastName.Trim().ToLower() == t.FirstLastName.Trim().ToLower(), may be give that a try

Comment: Why not using a `ObservableCollection<cEmployee>` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are all guaranteed to have a `FirstName` property one option is to use `dynamic`

```
if (!People.Any((dynamic x) => x.FirstName == t.FirstName)) { 
  ...
}
```

This isn't type safe but will function if all values do indeed have the property. If on the other hand they all implement a common base type or interface with the `FirstName` property then you can use that

```
if (!People.OfType<TheType>().Any(x => x.FirstName == t.FirstName)) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never came across dynamic. This is it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to call `People.Add(new cEmployee(t))`, and not `People.Add((cEmployee)t)` or even just `People.Add(t)` ?